# Ruby: pretty_print in pry: delegating to inspect leads to unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby, pretty-print, pry

Delegating *pretty_print* to *to_s* works as expected:

```
class R < Range
  def pretty_print(pp)    
    pp.text(to_s)        
  end       
end  
# => :pretty_print

r = R.new(1, 10)
#=> 1..10
```

But delegating to *inspect* produces unexpected represenation:

```
class R < Range
  def pretty_print(pp)    
    pp.text(inspect)
  end       
end  
# => :pretty_print

r = R.new(1, 10)
#=> (... .. ...)
```

Why?

Comment: That is, indeed, curious.

Comment: [`Range#inspect`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c#L1265) and [`Range#to_s`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c#L1222) are not the same thing so I think your super call is the issue here. Hint: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c#L1242

Comment: @engineersmnky I've streamlined my question (calls to *super* removed). *(1..10).to_s* and *(1..10).inspect* return the same output *1..10* . It is weird that calling *inspect* from an inherited level changes it's behavior. If inherited the call to inspect_range(VALUE range, VALUE dummy, int recur) seems to have the arg *recur* set to *true*. I could not figure out what this arg means. I either could not figure why this arg is set differently if called from inherited level.